# Calendar Date String Conversion in Fill Method with specific query

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I am using this query to generate a DataTable to display information for users to select from. The fill method I am using gives teh ff error.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string

```sql
SELECT        Time_Slot.TimeSlot, Proposed_Date.Date
FROM            Time_Slot CROSS JOIN
                         Proposed_Date
WHERE        (Time_Slot.TimeSlot_ID NOT IN
                             (SELECT        Event_Time_ID
                               FROM            Event_Booking
                               WHERE        (Booking_Date = @Booking_Date)))
```

```vb
DTAvailableBookingsTableAdapter.FillAvailableBookings(DSEventBooking.DTAvailableBookings, MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString)
```

Any help in resolving the error would be welcome

Answer (score 1):

Many people make their own lives difficult when it comes to dates. VB.NET has a dedicated data type for dates so, if you are working with dates, use it. Don't convert anything that is not text to text, unless it is specifically for display/serialisation purposes, where only text is supported.

Presumably your `Booking_Date` is the appropriate data type for dates in your database, e.g. `Date/Time` in Access or `date` in SQL Server. In that case, the `@Booking_Date` parameter is expecting a value of that type, not text. In that case, why are you converting a value of the correct type to a value of the incorrect type here:

```vb
MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString
```

The `Start` property is the correct type and you spoil it by converting it to a `String`. Don't. Just pass the `DateTime` value that you already have because that is what's expected.

```vb
MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start
```

Coming from a `MonthCalendar`, it should already have the time portion zeroed so there's no need to do that yourself but, in cases where you did need to, you can get the `Date` property of a `DateTime` value to get another `DateTime` value with the same date and the time zeroed.

```vb
MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date
```

Note that `DateTime` is a .NET type and VB has a `Date` type that is simply an alias for that, i.e. a `Date` and a `DateTime` are the same thing. If this is confusing, it shouldn't be. `Int32` is a .NET type too and `Integer` is a VB data type that maps to it. Do you use `Integer` all the time without any confusion? If so then you should use `Date` all the time without confusion too.

Comment: I have tried using: MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date. But the error still occurs

Comment: What database are you using? What is the data type of all the columns that store dates? What is the type of the exception? Please update your question with this information.

Comment: I'm using using Microsoft sql server. Data type of the Date column is 'date'. Type of exception: Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

Comment: @Kayla The same error message? SqlException is used for every error. If it is the exact same error message I would recommend checking the type of the parameter in the tableadapter, though why it would have detected as string when you claim the column is date, is unclear

Comment: @kayla Nothing stopping you posting screenshots into your question- open snipping tool, snip the error, press ctrl  c, edit your question, press ctrl v. I recommend you remove your email address from being publicly posted on the internet before too many spam harvesters catch it